# SQL Query to return all of the same numbers ignoring if the number is positive or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for an SQL query to return all records based on a number. The trick is that the number can be positive or negative, but as long as the number is the same it should return.

So I have a table like this:

```
1   amt1     100.00    
2   amt2     100.00    
3   amt3    -100.00    
4   amt4     120.00
```

A query such as this:

```
Select * from table where amount = '100.00'
```

Only returns the first 2 rows.

I want to return the first 3 rows, thus ignoring the minus sign but still matching the amount.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `in`:

```
where amount in (100.00, -100.00)
```

Note the single quotes are not necessary.

You can also use `abs()`:

```
where abs(amount) = 100.00
```

if you don't care much about indexes or query optimization.

Comment: I prefer the abs() solution as the user inputs the value and can either input as just 100.00 or as -100.00

Comment: If performance turns out to be bad, you can always [put an index on a computed column](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-indexes/sql-server-indexes-on-computed-columns/)

Answer (score 0):

If `amount` is a number:

```
select * from table where abs(amount) = 100.00;
```

If `amount` is text:

```
select * from table where amount in ('100.00', '-100.00');
```